# Casting a pointer when passing it as an argument for void* parameter

Tags: c++

Lets have following function:

```
int encode(uint8b *dest, MyType srcType, const void *src)
{
    uint32b value = 0;
    uint64b value64 = 0;

    switch (srcType)
    {
        case MyType_Usint:  value = (uint32b)*(uint8b*)src; break;
        case MyType_Uint:   value = (uint32b)*(uint16b*)src; break;
        case MyType_Udint:  value = *(uint32b*)src; break;
        case MyType_Ulint:  value64 = *(uint64b*)src; break;
    }
    // now encode value to dest
}
```

I have passed wrongly aligned `uint8b Data[sizeof(uint64b)]`as `src`, I will fix the alignment.

But I received a demand to cast `Data` when calling the function to proper type, i.e. `encode(dest, MyType_Uint, (uint16b*)Data)`, which I think would cause in some more annoying unnecessary switches.
It's working even with the wrong alignment on platforms accessible for me, but I'm not sure, how it affects the other.

Would such cast fix alignment and/or endianess?

And yes, I **really** need the `void*` parameter.

Comment: What is `Data` ?

Comment: Such cast would be utterly pointless.

Comment: @n.m. For `Usint` and `Uint` they are required (let's say you have `0xAABBCCDD` in memory pointed at src, then value in the former will be either `0xAA` or `0xDD`, depending on endianess with the cast, and `0xAABBCCDD` without). The cast to `uint32b` is useless.

Comment: @xryl669 Nope. It doesn't matter what you have in memory. You have a chain of *pointer* casts and implicit conversions. Inserting another cast to a different pointer type *in the middle of the chain* won't change the end result.

Comment: Read the code again. It's doing `*(uint8*)src`, notice the first star here. It's dereferencing the address here as a uint8, so only a single byte is read here. Without this cast, the meaning of the code changes. You're right that the cast to `uint32` is useless.

Comment: @xryl669 **you** read the code again. The question is whether the cast in `encode(dest, MyType_Uint, (uint16b*)Data)` makes any difference. It is the **first** cast in the chain. You are pointing at the **last** cast in the chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> encode(dest, MyType_Uint, (uint16b*)Data)
> ```
>
> Would such cast fix alignment and/or endianess?

Such cast does not fix alignment nor endiannes.

The way to call that function without undefined behaviour is following:

```
uint16b u = some_value;
encode(dest, MyType_Uint, &u);

uint64b ul = some_other_value;
encode(dest, MyType_Ulint, &ul);
```

> Does such cast actually do anything?

Such cast changes the type of the expression. In this case, the C style explicit conversion does reinterpret cast.

The converted pointer can be used only in limited ways. You can convert it back to the original type (`uint8b*` in your case). Indirection through the pointer is UB in most cases, with few exceptions, which include pointer-interconvertible objects, as well as using a pointer to a narrow character type as the result of the conversion. There is no exception that would apply to your example, so it would have UB.

Note that for some pointers, the C style explicit conversion does static cast, rather than reinterpret cast. For example, when the pointers are to classes in the same inheritance hierarchy. This is why C style casts are to be avoided: Use the cast that you intend to use.

Comment: No, that's wrong. `u` should be a uint64, not less, since in the case `MyType_Ulint` it'll be accessed as a uint64.

Comment: @xryl669 The case `MyType_Ulint` won't be executed when the argument isn't `MyType_Ulint`.

Comment: Since it's a runtime argument, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @xryl669 being a runtime argument makes no difference. The function has well defined behaviour when called like I've shown (assuming the redacted part actually `return`s).

Comment: No it does not. The standard expects that dereferencing a pointer to an object should have an object at the specified address, else it's UB. In case `MyType_Ulint` there is no guaranty it does (and to be clear, it does not in the OP's given use case), so this code presents UB. It's not because your example only use a limited (and correct) case that the rest of the bad code will magically become correct.

Comment: @xryl669 If you pass `MyType_Ulint` as the second argument, then you must of course pass pointer to an `uint64b` into the function. But that is irrelevant when `MyType_Ulint` is not passed as the second argument.

Comment: If I follow your logic, then the 2nd argument is useless, just write as many encode function as what you need (one for char, one for short, ...) and use that type for the last argument. Yet, the code, **as written** present UB since you can pass any 2nd argument you want and an unrelated pointer type for the last argument and it'll compile but behave undefinedly (likely crash)

Comment: @xryl669 Indeed the function presents UB in the same sense that for example the subscript operator of a vector or `memcpy` presents UB. The function has pre-conditions that must be obeyed, or else there is UB.

Comment: OK, I understand that I have to keep sane alignment and srcType. More general questions is: Does such cast actually do anything?

Comment: From a functional point of view, no they don't. From a correctness point of view, they tell the code's reader what was the intent. Yet, this function is prone to error, please check my answer for a solution that's deducing the type by itself, and avoid the alignment issue when you give it the correct type directly.

Answer (score 2):

Casting a pointer never fix alignment nor endianness. It just re-interpret the address as pointing to a different type, and standard does not allow to de-reference it unless an object of the appropriate type lies at that address.

The conformant way to use a possibly misaligned representation is to use `memcpy`:

```
int encode(uint8b *dest, MyType srcType, const void *src)
{
    uint32b value = 0;
    uint64b value64 = 0;

    switch (srcType)
    {
        // any object can be accessed through a char pointer
        case MyType_Usint:  uint8b tmp8 = *(uint8b*)src; value = tmp8; break;
        // use a temporary for 16 bits type (endianness question)
        case MyType_Uint:   uint16b tmp16; memcpy(&tmp16, src, sizeof(tmp16));
                            value = tmp16; break;
        // directly memcpy into the value when size is the same
        case MyType_Udint:  memcpy(&value, src, sizeof(value)); break;
        case MyType_Ulint:  memcpy(&value64, src, sizeof(value64)); break;
    }
    // now encode value to dest
}
```

Intel type (80x86 to core) are known to be tolerant to misalignment, but other processors are not and raise an error if you attempt a misaligned access.

Answer (score 1):

This code is unlikely to work on platform that can't do unaligned memory access (like ARM9/ARM64 etc...). 
This is because when you do `value64 = *(uint64b*)src` you expect the CPU to access a 8 bytes word (and as such it must be aligned to 64bit address) and the signature of the function does not guaranty this.

Typically, on such platform, calling:

```
  char s;
  int a = encode(dest, MyType_Ulint, &s);
```

will compile, and will crash at runtime (but will run ok on x86/amd64 system, yet with undefined behavior).

If you want something portable, you should do something like this:

```
enum MyType
{
   MyType_Usint,
   MyType_Uint,
   MyType_Udint,
   MyType_Ulint
};

int encode(uint8b *dest, MyType srcType, const void *src)
{
    uint32b value = 0;
    uint64b value64 = 0; // This is guaranted to be aligned for 64bit access
    size_t expected_operand_size[] = { 1, 2, 4, 8 };  
    memcpy(&value64, src, expected_operand_size[(int)srcType]); 

    switch (srcType)
    {
        case MyType_Usint:  value = *(uint8b*)&value64; break;
        case MyType_Uint:   value = *(uint16b*)&value64; break;
        case MyType_Udint:  value = *(uint32b*)&value64; break;
        case MyType_Ulint:  break;
    }
    // now encode value to dest
}
```

By the way, you should use template code here for convenience and to avoid the (useless) copy and be easier to understand (no need to have an type enum) :

```
template <typename T>
struct Encode
{
    static uint64b convert(const void * src) { T t; memcpy(&t, src, sizeof(t)); return t; }
    static uint64b convert(const T * src) { return *src; }
};

// Specialisation when we can avoid the copy
template <>
struct Encode<uint8b>
{
    static uint64b convert(const void * src) { return (uint8b)*src; }
    static uint64b convert(const uint8b * src) { return *src; }
};

template <typename T>
int encode(uint8b * dest, const void* src) 
{ 
   uint64b value64 = Encode<T>::convert(src);
   // your encoding code here
}
// Use like this:
void * s = ...;
uint16b * s2 = ...;
uint32b * s3 = ...;
encode<uint8b>(dest, s); // No copy, calls Encode<uint32b>::do(const void*)
encode<uint16b>(dest, s2); // No copy, calls Encode<uint16b>::do(const uint16b*)
encode<uint32b>(dest, s3); // No copy, calls Encode<uint32b>::do(const uint32b*)
// or this is also safe
encode<uint16b>(dest, s); // Copy here for fixing alignment
```

Comment: I can't / don't want to use compile-time types here.

Comment: Then use the former code block. It'll not crash unless `src` points to some invalid address.